# Bootstrap: Display multiple carousel in a boostrap grid format

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

There are dynamically generated N carousel, each containing 1 or more images. I want to display them in a grid format in a neat way. Right now it is appearing in horizontal format.

**Current formation:**

[image]

I am using Bootstrap4. Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Existing code, which uses jinja template:

```
{% for track_id, image_path in image_urls.items %}
        <div>
            <div id="nCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    {% for ip in image_path %}
                    <!-- <h1> Index: {{ forloop.counter }}</h1> -->
                    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ ip }}" >
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ ip }}" >
                    </div>
                    {{ forloop.length }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#nCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#nCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <style> .carousel {
            width:180px;
            height:180px;
        }</style>
```

Comment: REQUEST: Before further downvoting, can you please tell me what's the issue with the question so that I can make it more clear for the fellow users? I really don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [code snippet](https://www.codeply.com/go/Waw2GLkzQq/bootstrap-4-carousel-with-grid-columns). I think it's what are you looking for.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I want to see in a different rows instead of having it inside another slider.

Comment: @disp_name ok, you can try to add every carousel inside a separate row

Comment: Sure, I will try it and will accept once done. Thank you so much :)